# make div 'fadeOut' and then 'fadeIn' in different place

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So here is the deal. I am trying to build interactive list (just like ToDo list). My task is that on click 'div.item'should disappear (fadeOut) from "container" and then fadeIn in "trash can".
Here is the code, but when I run it, all animation happens in "trash can". I tried to set a variable equals to my ".item" and make manipulations with it, still no result.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="createList.js">

  $(document).on('click', '.item', function (){
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
        $(this).appendTo('#shoppingChart').fadeIn('slow');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to animate, then run the function to append -

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function (){
    $(this).fadeOut('slow',function () {
         $(this).appendTo('#shoppingChart').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});​
```

**Edit** -- working example - http://jsfiddle.net/jmsessink/NHtv4/

Answer (score 1):

The fading methods are non-blocking, so they won't prevent subsequent methods from taking place. If you wish to wait until they've finished before you continue, use their callbacks:

```
// Listen for any click on an img within #desktop
$("#desktop").on("click", "img", function () {
    // Fade that image out over a second
    $(this).fadeOut(1000, function () {
        // When fade is complete, move item and fade-in
        $(this).appendTo("#trash").fadeIn();
    });
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9U2dP/

You could also use a deferred:

```
// Listen for any click on an img within #desktop
$("#desktop").on("click", "img", function () {
    // When our hide instruction is done
    $.when($(this).hide(1000)).done(function(item){
        // Append the item to #trash, and fade it into view
        $(item).appendTo("#trash").fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9U2dP/3/

Comment: Looks like @JSess beat you to it, but you get all the props for using placekitten in your example :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for animation to finish, then append item to trash can, then fade in.

Here is a working demo:
http://jsbin.com/ipovic/1/edit

Comment: That wouldn't explain why the element wasn't moved.

Comment: Element was moved, may be I just explained it wrong. Thanks, it works fine!

Comment: Glad to hear that :) You can accept a solution if your problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/A7GLb/1/)

The fade operations are asynchronous, so invoking the methods simply triggers the action—the next call doesn't wait for it to complete. To show both parts of the animation, delay following actions by a time constant using JavaScript's native [setTimeout method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout).

This example code allots 1 second for the fade-out action, stops the animation wherever it is after that point, then triggers the fade-in action appropriately.

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function (){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.fadeOut('slow');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.stop()
            .appendTo('#shoppingChart')
            .fadeIn('slow');
    }, 1000);
});​
```